# No logro hacer funcionar correctamente una función en la que agrego y retiro elementos según diferentes condiciones. Javascript

Tags: string, condiciones

Implementar la función crearStack, la cual recibirá por parámetro un string.
El string recibido tendrá un formato de sucesión de letras y astericos, de la siguiente manera:
"UN*A*PAL*AB*RA"
"OTR*A**PAL**ABR*A"
crearStack debe retornar false en caso de recibir un string vacío.
Caso contrario, deberá crear un Stack, al que se agregarán y retirarán valores EN ORDEN según la secuencia recibida
en el string, siguiendo la siguiente lógica:
Una letra (A , B , C) -> Agregar la letra al Stack
Un asterisco (*) -> Retirar un elemento del Stack
Finalmente, la función deberá retornar el Stack resultante.
Asimismo, debo prevenir que la función intente retirar un elemento del Stack si el mismo está vacío, en cuyo caso
la función deberá retornar el string "Stack vacío"
EJEMPLOS:

````
crearStack("EJ*EMP*LO") => [E,E,M,L,O]
crearStack("OTR**OEJEM***PL*O") => [O,O,E,P,O]
crearStack("") => false
crearStack("RET****ORNA**R*FA*L**SO") => "Stack vacío"

Esto es lo que me devuelve mi funcion:

crearStack("EJ***EMP*LO"); [ 'E', 'J', 'E', 'M', 'P', 'L', 'O' ]
crearStack("EJ*EMP*LO")   [ 'E', 'J', 'E', 'M', 'P', 'L', 'O' ]

y el codigo es este:

``

function crearStack(palabra) {
  
  let stack = [];
    
    if(palabra.length === 0){
        return false
    }

   for(let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++){{
     if(typeof palabra[i] === "string"){
       stack.push(palabra[i])
    } 
      if(palabra[i] === "*"){
        stack.pop()
      if(stack.length === 0) return "Stack vacío"
     }
  }
   
  }
  return stack;
}

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tienes en tu código, solo tienes que cambiar un poco el orden dentro del ciclo `for`.

Primero preguntas si la letra actual es un asterisco. Si no es un asterisco pues la agregas y sigues a la siguiente letra.

Si en cambio, es un asterisco, verificas si el stack está vacío. Si está vacío devuelves "Stack vacío". Si no está vacío, haces un pop.

El código quedaría:

```js
function crearStack(palabra) {
    let stack = [];

    if (palabra.length === 0) {
        return false
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
        {
            if (palabra[i] === "*") {
                if (stack.length === 0) return "Stack vacío"
                stack.pop()
            } else {
                stack.push(palabra[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return stack;
}

console.log(crearStack("EJ*EMP*LO"))
console.log(crearStack("OTR**OEJEM***PL*O"))
console.log(crearStack(""))
console.log(crearStack("RET****ORNA**R*FA*L**SO"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco por la ayuda Jaime.